# Vis.js Timeline not showing only one today item

Tags: vis.js

If I want show only one item for today, nothing are shown, ex: (Change the date for today)

```js
// DOM element where the Timeline will be attached
var container = document.getElementById('visualization');

// Create a DataSet (allows two way data-binding)
var items = new vis.DataSet([
  {id: 1, content: 'item 1', start: '2021-12-16'},
]);

// Configuration for the Timeline
var options = {};

// Create a Timeline
var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options);
```

Example Code Pen: https://codepen.io/nuno-soares-the-scripter/pen/xxXqvLP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked CodePen is using vis.js v4.21.0 which was released in October 2017 and is now deprecated as per https://github.com/almende/vis. The issue described at https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/3616 is occurring in this older version. This causes `visibility: hidden;` to be added to the visualization elements inline CSS.

Two ways to resolve this:

#### 1. Update to vis-timeline

Update from the depreciated vis.js v4.21.0 to the latest version. After vis.js was depreciated the components were split into separate modules, the module for the timeline being vis-timeline at https://github.com/visjs/vis-timeline.

As per the GitHub example the JavaScript and CSS sources should be updated. Updating these on the CodePen displays the timeline.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/vis-timeline@latest/standalone/umd/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vis-timeline@latest/styles/vis-timeline-graph2d.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

#### 2. Set Start Date

If you cannot use vis-timeline and must remain on this depreciated version then adding a start date to the options object will also display the timeline.

```js
var options = {start:'2021-12-16'};
```